# Why locally compact in the Gelfand representation?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

I'm missing something in the Gelfand representation. Let's just say $\mathfrak{A}$ is a Banach algebra. Then it's a Banach space, and so we have $\mathfrak{A}^\ast$. The multiplicative linear functionals on $\mathfrak{A}$ are continuous and have norm $\leq 1$, and so still sit inside the unit ball of $\mathfrak{A}$, which is weak-$\ast$ compact. The set of multiplicative linear functionals are weak-$\ast$ closed, so the set of mulitplicative linear functionals is then weak-$\ast$ compact.

Where does not having a unit make the above not work? I always see that the multiplicative linear functionals are locally compact in the non-unital case, but I cannot spot where the unit is needed in the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $A$ is non-unital. Denote by $X(A)$ the space of its characters and denote 
$$
X(A)_+=X(A)\cup\{0\}
$$ 
One can show that $X(A)_+$ is weak-$^*$ closed subset of weak-$^*$ compact unit ball of $A^*$. So $X(A)_+$ is weak-$^*$ compact.

One can show that $X(A)_+$ is a one point compactification of $X(A)$, so $X(A)$ is locally compact.

Comment: I mean, if everything I said in my post was true, then $X(A)$ was compact to begin with, and so is of course locally compact. But why don't any of the references I see just outright say it's compact? All of them merely say it's locally compact, so there must be some flaw in the logic of the original post. Finding the flaw is what I'm after.

Comment: The problem is that $X(A)$ is weak-$^*$ closed iff $A$ is unital. For non-unital case $0$ is a touching point of $X(A)$, but $0\notin X(A)$ because of the definition of $X(A)$. Sorry I'll be back in two hours then we can continue if you want.

Comment: No, thank you. I see what's wrong, and working this out myself will be good for me.