# Unitization of Banach algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Is every theorem about unital Banach algebra also true for non-unital Banach algebras because of unitization?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320546/why-locally-compact-in-the-gelfand-representation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course not. For example the Gelfand spectrum of Banach algebra is locally compact, and it is compact iff $A$ is unital. There a lot of examples in Banach homology where existence of unit plays significant role.

Another example which is more related to Banach space geometry than to Banach algebras: the Banach algebra $c_0$ have no extreme points while its unitization $c$ have $\mathfrak{c}$ extreme points.

Comment: If you can I'd appreciate an example of an algebra $A$ such that its unitization gets a property that $A$ does not have. Since $A$ embeds into its unitizazion it seems to be that whatever is true about the whole space (the unitization) is also true in the subspace $A$.

Comment: @Student, see edit of my answer

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much!

Comment: I'm sorry, is the Gelfand spectrum the same as the space of characters?

Comment: yes$\phantom{}$